# VBA to check workbook for array of values, IF exists, output on 6th column of that value row

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help and guidance. I saw examples for nested IFs alternatives but nothing on writing output on the same row of value, different column.

If workbook contains `ABCDXYZ` in column A of any sheet, output returns `=8*8` in the 6th cell from the right of `ABCDXYZ`. If workbook contains `ABCEFG` in column A of any sheet, output returns `=8*8` in the 6th cell from the right of `ABCEFG`.

IE: `ABCDXYZ` is in worksheet 3, in cell A1, output to be written in cell G1 is `=8*8` and in worksheet 5, in cell A33, output to be written in cell G33 is `=8*8`.

If `ABCEFG` is in Worksheet 7, in well A4, output to be written in cell G4 is `=8*4`.

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: If you haven't tried anything then [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. Let me study that first and see if I can incorporate it into what I'm doing. I'm using it for work (though I'm in HR) so I'd have to change all the specific variables and values before posting haha.